# Azure SQL Alerts to integrate with TEAMS

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I am trying to integrate Azure SQL Alerts with Teams. I have created webbook and the link I got paste it into Azure action group. When I run a test it has fail output. So then I have created runbook and within the runbook created webbook. The link I got from the webbook I inserted into the action group when run test it was successful. I can see the alert in the azure runbook/webbook but didn't come trough TEAMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Follow these steps to achieve the Alert goals

**Step 1: Create a blank Logic App**

•   For this step, you need to login to the Azure portal and create a new Logic App. Once you’re in the right place, click on the Add menu and select the Logic App type you want to create. The available types are: Standard and Consumption. You can find all the necessary info in the page Pricing and billing models for Azure Logic Apps at [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-pricing)

**Step 2: Configure the Logic App**

•   In the Logic App designer page, click on the When a HTTP request is received. This will be our trigger .

•   After the selection, you will be presented with the Logic App designer canvas. This is where we will do all our remaining configurations starting with the trigger activity we just added

•   Configure the activity with the JSON schema that the trigger will use. Since the request will contain the alert’s JSON payload, you can refer (and use) the sample schema you can find in the article Common alert schema definitions at [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-common-schema-definitions) .Copy the sample alert payload from the page, click on Use sample playload to generate schema, paste the content and click Done

•   To create a condition used to decide which notification activity to use, click on the New Step, in the search box type Control

•   Select the Control group and then select the Switch activity to add it to the canvas. For groups with lots of activities, you can enter the activity name or part of it in the search box.

Once added, this activity needs some configuration:
Team ID,Channel, Message

As far as the Team ID and the Channel go, you can select Azmon alert,With regards to the Message body part, this is representing the information sent through the notification. Here you can enter static text formatted as you like, dynamic content as well as formulas. In my example I started with a kind of title and followed with sections under which there are the info I wanted to send. For the static text, you just need to write it. For the dynamic content and/or formulas, once you decided the line where to put it, click on Add dynamic content and select it from the side panel click in the Message canvas and either select it from the Dynamic content list or assemble it using the Expression builder

In this post, since I got everything correctly parsed from the trigger activity (the When a HTTP request is received), I will go use the dynamic content only. For instance, after having put some text like – Alert Id: I will select alertId content from the list

**Step 3: Configure the Action Group**

configure an Action Group to use it in order receive our alerts as expected.From the Azure Monitor blade

•   From the Alerts page, click on Manage actions

•   Click on New action group

•   Enter the necessary basic information and click on Next: Notifications

•   Configure the following according to what has been created before:

o   Action type

o   Name

o   Selected

•   making sure to enable the common alert schema and select and create

**Step 4: Add the new action group to your alerts**

we have the Action group created and configured; we need to add it to all the alerts we want to notify

•   From the Alerts page, click on Manage alert rules

•   In the Actions section, add the new action group to the existing one (or remove them if not necessary

•   Select the newly created (and de-select the selected ones if necessary) and click Select

•   Click Save to save and apply the changes

**Step 5: Test**

Refer below doc

**[link](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/core-infrastructure-and-security/azure-monitor-alert-notification-via-teams/ba-p/2507676)**

Comment: Thank you Chris for the useful answer. I have indeed triggered the push and I am able to receive messages on teams. However, When using dynamic content in my post a message to a chat or channel section it doesnt appear on teams message. Comes back blank. Any suggestions?